# cannot remote connect to the postgresql server

Tags: postgresql

I have an Ubuntu guest installed on my mac using virtualbox and vagrant.  I installed the postgresql 9.3 on ubuntu.

I try to connect it from the host OS. kept getting operation time out. Is the server running on host "11.11.11.18" and accepting TCP/IP connection on port 5432.

i tried following, still not working.

in vagrant file.

```
ubuntu.vm.network "private_network", ip: "11.11.11.18"
ubuntu.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306
ubuntu.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 5432
```

pg_hba.conf

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

what else do i need to check?

Comment: If you forward a port - you need to connect to localhost

Comment: @zerkms, thank you. it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you forward ports - you need to connect to `localhost` instead.